# Why does water ice on the Moon not sublime?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, moon

I heard that water in form of ice was found on the Moon. Why would the ice not sublime (evaporate) due to low atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Please clarify your question to indicate what's not clear from the information at [If there is actual ice on the moon, why hasn't it sublimated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21381/), for example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://space.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @annav If it is not Physics to explain under which condition sublimation can become ineffective, I do not know what this site should be about.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 it is about mainstream physics questions , no applications to any possible situation. There are a large number of such  SE sites. Should they all end up in physics?